# How to set html and body tags to wrap the full screen?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do it is that my `html` and `body` tags occupy the full screen of any computer. The limits of the screen depending of the screen of each computer **without scrollbars or `overflow:hidden` property.**

This is my simple `HTML` code:

```
<body>
  <div id="centerDiv"></div>
</body>
```

---

***Prove 1***

So what I have tried in a first instance it is to set the `html` and `body` tag with `height: 100%;` but a scroll appears on the screen. This is my `CSS`:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#centerDiv{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

and you have the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9kvb9L6/) in which you can see the scroll.

---

***Prove 2***

Then, after seeing that the scroll appears, I tried changing `html` tag to `min-height: 100%;` so the `html` tag will be like this:

```css
html{
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

and you can see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9kvb9L6/1/) in which you can see that the scroll dissapears but the `body` tag does not occupy the full screen.

---

***Prove 3***

Also, I tried to set both `html` and `body` tags with `min-height: 100%;` but the result it is the same as in the case 2.

---

I supposed that `min-height: 100%;`, as its name indicates, would be the default height taking as reference the height of the parent, but it does not seem to work. [Here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18714) it was posted as a bug, but not in case of using it on `html` or `body` tags.

Looking around Stackoverflow I could see that in some cases people use `display:table` for the parent element and `display: table-row;` for the child elements when they are using `min-height` on the parent element but as in this case I am using the `html` and `body` tags I do not know if it is very appropriate to set both tags display as a `table`.

The performance that I want it is that my webpage looks like my second one prove, but with `body` tag wrapping all the screen also.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: don't forget to do `padding: 0; margin: 0`.

Comment: I would consider to add `overflow:hidden` as well to hide all scrollbars, in case you don't want them when user triggers a browser action (ex: Chrome opening downloads toolbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<body>` has default `margin`, so you need to reset `margin` on `<body>`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0
}
#centerDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="centerDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @dippas's solution using viewport units:

```css
*, :before, :after {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Consider that on Edge and IE support isn't full yet, you could check here http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: `Partial support refers to not supporting the "vmax" unit.` -- `vmax` is not used here, but still good to point out.

Comment: Just in case :) also when you want to support older IE versions (I mean almost all front-end developers tend to pretend they don't exist, I live more happy that way) this could cause issues

Comment: I must say it's hard to bring up a good case in trying to support the 1.5% of users who still use older versions of IE, especially when Microsoft has dropped support for their own IE line completely. There are cases when it makes sense to do so, but it would be more the exception than the rule.